# Create new Rails app with pg_restore data dump

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have the raw output of a `pg_restore` data dump, and need to build an app around the data set to analyze what's inside.

So far, I created a new Rails app, set up my `database.yml` file to talk to the correct Postgres database, and ran `pg_restore`.  The database looks to be OK in Postgres

My question is, how can I start to connect to these tables using Rails and ActiveRecord so that I can start to make sense of what's inside?  I'd prefer to do the analyses using AR and Rails rather than just in the pg console

1) Do I need to create a Model for every table that was imported with `pg_restore`?

**Sample Output:**  (Note the table exists if I search all table names in the Rails console, but I am unable to actually connect to it)

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.3)
2.1.4 :001 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.sort[1]
 => "actstream_follow" 
2.1.4 :002 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.sort.each do |table|
2.1.4 :003 >     next if table.match(/\Aschema_migrations\Z/)
2.1.4 :004?>   klass = table.singularize.camelize.constantize     
2.1.4 :005?>   puts "#{klass.name} has #{klass.count} records"
2.1.4 :006?>   end
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "actstream_actions" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started thinking of ways to do this, then my "look for a gem" reminder kicked in. I would try this:

https://github.com/bosko/rmre

I looks like it can generate all of your models, primary keys, correct naming conventions and even foreign keys in Postgres and others.

Comment: Yep. The term you are looking for is "reverse engineer", in the sense of "reverse engineer a database to create a model"

Comment: 1,000,000 times yes! This little gem just created 140 models for me in ~3 seconds, and saved me about a week's worth of work. Thank you!